# Binary image loaded from server to image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, binary, xmlhttprequest

I'm loading a jpeg image from my server in binary format via XMLHttpRequest (I need it that way). It's not base64 encoded.

Is it possible to turn it to an img object with javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the character encoding of the `XMLHttpRequest` has been set to [something that won't change the binary data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Handling_binary_data), or you've [set the response type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), you can then run `.responseText` through `btoa` (putting it in base64 and letting you assign it as a data URI) or access `.response` for the binary data, respectively.

---

Assuming your instance is named `xhr` and you're using the charset method before `xhr.send` but after `xhr.open` do

```
xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
```

then when you're `200 OK`

```
var dataURI = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(xhr.responseText);
```

Which you can then set as a *src* of an `<img>`.

---

Again assuming `xhr`, this time `.response` method; between `.open` and `.send`,

```
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

Then at `200 OK`

```
var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(xhr.response), // can choose 8, 16 or 32 depending on how you save your images
    blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], {'type': 'image\/jpeg'}),
    objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Which you can then set as a *src* of an `<img>`. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSJpc/2/)

Comment: This is called an inline image. Note that IE8 only supports inline images that are less than 32 KB (for the base64 encoded data, so the source image would have to be less than 24 KB), and IE7 and earlier don't support inline images at all (if that matters).

Comment: Tried that, but `btoa(xhr.responseText)` keeps returning `Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5`. I cannot find why this happens. 
For IE7/IE8... I will have to make a Flash object to deal with it grrr

Comment: @Marc that happens because `btoa` has some [bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213047) (same/similar also applies to webkit), I'll update answer with an _ArrayBuffer_ -> `Blob` -> through _URL.createObjectURL_ method, which in my opinion is slightly better than through _FileReader_ but still not as nice as _btoa_.

Comment: As for the compatibility of this method, [looks like](http://caniuse.com/#search=Blob) IE10+